# slow the answers from chatbot on facebook

Tags: php, facebook, chatbot

I am using php for chatbot, and code looks like it:

```
$bot->send(new Message($message['sender']['id'], "Say 1"));    
sleep(7);
$bot->send(new Message($message['sender']['id'], "Say 2"));
```

When the sleep time is big, e.x. more than 4 or 5, I don't know why, but I got from user one by one completely the same answers. I am not sure, but it seems to me, that because of the sleep, facebook thinks that the message is not delivered from user and sends completely the same messages... Could you tell me any ideas about it or how to slow down the bot answers?

p.s. I divide the text into two messages to present it in a more pretty way for user.

Comment: Facebook expects a quick response from your bot. Adding sleep between to calls of that function will only achieve that the answer to the request you got from Facebook is dragged out. You will need to send just the initial response in answer to that incoming request, and then send the rest later, independent from the request Facebook send to you.

Comment: What do you mean with "independent from the request Facebook send to you", do I need to create the new variable ($bot = new FbBotApp($token)) and use it instead to send my further messages?

Comment: I mean that you need some other mechanism to trigger your script in certain intervals, like cron, so that it can send the queued messages without being trigger by an incoming request from messenger.